# Serverless Web Application (AWS) vs Angular Web Application hosted on EC2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, serverless

I start building some a web using Angular 6 that will be hosted on EC2 (AWS), connect to RDS database etc.

Now I am reading about AWS Serverless Web Applications (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

What are Pros vs Cons in one approach vs the other?

Should I start thinking about scraping Angular Web package on EC2 and just focus on  AWS serverless approach?

Comment: I recommend reading Martin Fowler's article on [Serverless Architectures](https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html) and [The Comprehensive Guide to Serverless Architecture](https://www.simform.com/serverless-architecture-guide/). They have valuable information and describe the transition from monoliths > mircroservices > serverless. For me, the hardest part is that serverless requires to see things from a different angle. And context switching is expensive not only for CPUs but also for humans.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many comparisons around, but here are a few considerations I've come up with.

Pros for serverless:

- **Cheaper** - It tends to be cheaper (especially for low-traffic websites) since you don't have to pay for servers that are mostly idle.
- **Lower maintenance overhead** - You don't have to maintain servers (bootstrapping, updating/patching, etc.).
- **Scales automatically** - Lambda will automatically scale up to 1000 concurrently running functions, so you don't have to worry about auto scaling groups, load balancing, etc.
- **Easy to deploy** - Especially if you're using the [SAM CloudFormation resource types](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md).

Pros for servers:

- **More operating systems** - And consequently, more control over the runtime environment. For example, you're not restricted to Amazon Linux-compatible binaries if your EC2 instance is running Ubuntu or another operating system.
- **Concurrent connections** - You can only have 1000 concurrently running Lambda functions per account, but you can have fleets of EC2 instances that handle millions of concurrent connections.
- **Can allocate more memory per connection** - Lambda functions can only handle up to 3 GB memory, so depending on your memory needs, you may need a servered approach.
- **Latency** - Lambda cold starts can negatively impact your latency from time to time.

Comment: Thanks. One question - should this bullet go into 'Pros for servers' instead? (Latency - Lambda cold starts can negatively impact your latency from time to time.)

Comment: Good catch! I've updated my answer so it's listed under pros for servers now.

Comment: Cool, so if you would start a new web development - which way would you go now?

Comment: It really depends on the needs of the web service. But if it's just for learning, I'd give serverless a go so that at a minimum, you understand how serverless works and have firsthand experience with its capabilities and limitations. I have a feeling it'll become much more popular over time, as AWS, Azure, GCP, IBM Cloud, Alibaba Cloud and likely others are already offering serverless solutions.